# NestJS Durable provider: Retrieve tenantId from microservices context

Tags: database, microservices, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant platform. An issue that I've been facing is that: when I check the `x-tenant-id` in request header and `tenantId` from the Context between microservices, the database config running in request scope will cause multiple open database connection each request.

I've researched and found a solution by using [Durable Provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#durable-providers) from NestJS. This is the code that I use from the documentation

```
import {
  HostComponentInfo,
  ContextId,
  ContextIdFactory,
  ContextIdStrategy,
} from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

const tenants = new Map<string, ContextId>();

export class AggregateByTenantContextIdStrategy implements ContextIdStrategy {
  attach(contextId: ContextId, request: Request) {
    const tenantId = request.headers['x-tenant-id'] as string;
    console.log(request);

    let tenantSubTreeId: ContextId;

    if (tenants.has(tenantId)) {
      tenantSubTreeId = tenants.get(tenantId);
    } else {
      tenantSubTreeId = ContextIdFactory.create();
      tenants.set(tenantId, tenantSubTreeId);
    }

    return {
      resolve: (info: HostComponentInfo) =>
        info.isTreeDurable ? tenantSubTreeId : contextId,
      payload: { tenantId },
    };
  }
}
```

The `AggregateByTenantContextIdStrategy` works perfectly to solve the issue. However, it can check only the `x-tenant-id` from request header. When I tried to get `tenantId` from `ExecutionContext`, I couldn't retrieve the data or the context itself. Is there a way to retrieve that in the context between microservices?

I expect to get the data from microservices context

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am looking for the same thing. Please let me know, thanks!